# How to divide 3D cylinder into several segments

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, blender

I am working on a 3D Unity Game that mimics a Slot Machine. Each reels of slot, has 8 different symbols. I am able to load a sprite on the cylindrical reel as Texture. *Cylinder was imported from Blender.* Rotation of reels are done but to get more on that, I wanted to get the control over each segment (symbols) on the face of the reel. Is there a way I can divide and control the 3D cylinder, should it be done through code or when designing on blender. I hope I am explaining well.

Here's the conceptual image for the question
[image]

Comment: Can't you apply a texture that makes it appear to have multiple sections? As long as they're equally-sized, it shouldn't be hard to rotate the cylinder to show any particular one - just a bit of math involved.

Comment: @Serlite I have been working on math for a week but, couldn't figure out.

Comment: Hmm, what part is posing difficulties for you? In my mind, I'd imagine you just associate each section with a rotation (in this case, going up in increments of 8/360), then spinning to one of those angles when you want to display a symbol. (Unless you're talking about splitting up the cylinder *vertically* into sections that each display different symbols. In that case, same approach, but multiple thin cylinders.)

Answer (score 1):

You should draw your segments and make your cylinder from your segments and "explode" it when needed.

Comment: How is that done? should that be done in Blender or through script. Do you have any online resources that links to a good description on the same thing?

Comment: Thanks, I'll sure try solutions from that QA